# Parse JSON-Map to object with json_serializable when keys are unknown

Tags: json, flutter, dart, json-serialization

I want to deserialize an http-response of following format.

```
{
 "12-34": "some value",
 "45-67": "another value",
 ...
}
```

I don't know how to create a DTO class with json_serializable annotation if I don't know the keys and the number of keys returned from the backend. So in this DTO class I can't create variables that hold the values.

Is there any ability to create a DTO class with json_serializable annotation that only contains the referred map or can i use a class with following structure

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ResponseState {
  String number;
  String message;
 
  factory ResponseState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ResponseStateFromJson(json)
}
```

But how can i parse the json to a list of this objects?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear from your question, but if you have a JSON object containing arbitrary keys with `ResponseState` values, you can use [`Map.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.5/dart-core/Map/map.html):

```dart
final responseStates = (json as Map<String, dynamic>)
    .map((key, responseStateJson) => MapEntry(key, ResponseState.fromJson(responseStateJson)));
```